# csv writer splitting all commas in array

Tags: java, csv

I have the following String[] of length 7.

```
["column1Item", "column2Item", "column3Item", "column4Item", "column5Item", "column6Item,column6Item", "column7Item,column7Item"]
```

The 6th element is

```
"column6Item,column6Item"
```

The 7th element is

```
 "column7Item,column7Item"
```

When I write this to csv I get 8 columns instead of 6

```
column1Item,column2Item,column3Item,column4Item,column5Item,column5Item,column6Item,column6Item
```

Here is how I am currently writing to csv:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("output.csv"),',',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

writer.writeAll(newCsvBody);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: What is wrong with this approach? -> *CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER*. Quotes are used for enclosing values, so that any decent parser knows that a string with commas is a single value instead multiple. If you disable them, you can't escape commas anymore. Either avoid disabling quotes or change delimiter (that won't solve the issue though, as it will happen again when the new delimiter is used inside one of the columns)

Comment: There is something missing from your code, where does `column0Item` magically appear from? Also, if you use a character as separator which is also present as plain text, any interpreter would be confused whether to interpret the character as plain text or as separator.

Comment: It's unclear to me what your array contains.  For instance, is `column1Item` the name of a variable, or the literal String `"column1Item"`?  Does the array contain `column6Item` twice, or does it contain the String `"column6Item,column6Item"`?

Comment: no its not 9 elements, i cleary say what the 6th and 7th elements are.

Comment: i have editied the question make it clear that it is a string

Comment: Now your source array contains items 1 to 7 whilst your target contains items 0 to 6!?

Comment: i am very sorry about this, i have edited it again.

Answer (score 4):

Your csv delimiter also occurs inside your elements you're trying to write. Either use a different csv delimiter (eg semicolon) or escape the comma inside the 'column6Item,column6Item' and 'column7Item,column7Item' elements.

Comment: Or let the CSV have quote characters around strings, as said by @BackSlash in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

With below code, I am getting 7 columns.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         String[] ss =  {"column1Item", "column2Item", "column3Item", "column4Item", "column5Item", "column6Item,column6Item", "column7Item,column7Item"};
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.csv"); 
         OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
         CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(osw);
         writer.writeNext(ss);
         writer.close();
         osw.close();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

As comma is inside value, you should try with different delimiter like pipe sign(|).